# Passing parameter from get to post method

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm building an feature for a webste where a user can reset his password. He receives an email with a generated token in the url. When this link is clicked, the user is sent to the /reset page. The Get method for that page is the following:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/reset", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView displayResetPasswordPage(ModelAndView modelAndView, @ModelAttribute User user, @RequestParam("token") String token) {

    User u = userService.findByResetToken(token);


    if (u == null) {
        modelAndView.setViewName("error/404");
        return modelAndView;
    } else {
        modelAndView.addObject("token", token);
        modelAndView.setViewName("resetPassword");
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

This works fine, if the token in the url is changed, the user is sent to an error page. Now I want to pass this "token" parameter to the post method:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/reset", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView setNewPassword(ModelAndView modelAndView, @RequestParam Map<String, String> requestParams, @ModelAttribute User user, BindingResult bindingResult,  RedirectAttributes redir) {

    System.out.println("token: " + requestParams.get("token"));
    User u = userService.findByResetToken(requestParams.get("token"));

 //   User u = userService.findByEmail(user.getEmail());       


    if (u != null) {

        User updatedUser = userService.updateUserPassword(user);

        modelAndView.addObject("User",updatedUser);
        modelAndView.setViewName("redirect:login");
        return modelAndView;

    } else {
        modelAndView.setViewName("resetPassword");
    }

    return modelAndView;
}
```

This always returns the resetPassword view, since the requestparams.get("token") always returns an empty string. Am I not using the correct method to get the param value?

The reset password view:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<form class="form-signin" th:action="@{/reset}" method="post" th:object="${user}">
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Reset wachtwoord</h2>
    <input type="hidden" name="token" th:value="*{resetToken}"/>       
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" th:field="*{encryptedPassword}" id="password" class="form-control input-lg"
               placeholder="Password" tabindex="3"/>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" th:field="*{matchingPassword}" id="password_confirmation"
               class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Confirm Password" tabindex="4"/>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" value="Registreer"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: What's the "/reset" view looks like?

Comment: @LeoG. Edited my original post

Comment: shouldn't it be "token" instead of "resetToken" in your view, as you named it in your controller?

Comment: I renamed the modelAndView.addObject("token", token); to modelAndView.addObject("resetToken", token); but this didn't work either

Comment: have a custom DTO for this instead of user, may be a DTO that includes Userdetails plus the token

Comment: I think it should be a lot easier? I mean, the token is in the url ! I tried using Pathvariable but that gave me an error that said"String token parameter was not found" .

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by employing the `Flash Scope` that will allow your token to survive a `redirect`. You can do that by:

1. Making the first controller method accessing the second one via a `redirect`
2. Using `RedirectAttributes` on your first controller method and explicitly adding your token into the `RedirectAttributes` as a `Flash Attribute`

[Take a look at the documentation about RedirectAttributes](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-requestattrib).

Comment: I also tried this:   redirectAttributes.addAttribute("token", token); and followed  by return new ModelAndView("redirect:resetPassword"); Unfortunately, this threw an error which is weird because I use the same code in a different post method

Comment: Dont return a ModelAndView() but rather return a String type with return "redirect:resetPassword"

Comment: I modified the return type to String and added the following:
redirectAttributes.addAttribute("token", token);
return "redirect:resetPassword";
but know it sends me straight to the login page, which is the default page? I'm totally flabergasted :) I tried just returning "resetPassword" and that worked just fine.

Comment: I checked and the /reset page is already added to my spring security config, but for some reason when I add the attribute, the redirect is rejected?